How to define a canonical form similar with reduced row echelon form
It is well known that for any $m$ by $n$ matrix $M$, the class of matrices $[M]:=\{LM\mid L\text{ is an }m \text{ by } m \text{ invertible matrix}\}$ has a canonical form, which is the reduced row echelon form of $C$. This means that for any two $M_1,M_2\in[M]$, they always have the same canonical form (i.e., the reduced row echelon form). My question is that, what if we change the underlying equivalence class to $\{LMD\mid L\text{ is an }m \text{ by } m \text{ invertible matrix and } D\text{ is an }n \text{ by } n \text{ invertible diagonal matrix}\}$?
How can we define a canonical form in this case?

The usual canonical form here is
$$
\pmatrix{I_r & 0\0 & 0},
$$
where $I_r$ denotes an $r \times r$ identity matrix. Note that $r$ is equal to the rank of this canonical form matrix; the canonical form of a matrix is entirely determined by its shape and rank. I forget what the usual terminology is for this canonical form.

Note: the rank factorization can be seen as a compact version of a product of the form
$$
P \pmatrix{I_r & 0\0 & 0}Q,
$$
where $P$ and $Q$ are invertible.

@BenGrossmann Thanks for your answer. There is a slight variation in my question, that is, the right-acting matrix is not only invertible but also required to be diagonal.
